# google map placing locations with some distance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I'm new to ROR and Google Maps. I need to place some markers from locations in Google Maps (having latitudes and longitudes in a database).

The problem is that I need to select some points with some random distance.

In short, I need to select the location and place it in a map, which must have 100 m distance with each and every points.

**If the location is within 100 m range with any other points, it can be neglected. I need to place 10 points from database.**

Is there any method?

Comment: Please let me clarify: you have a database with about 50 to 100 points, clustered around a relatively small geographic area. You are trying to find 10 of these points that are further than 100 meters away from all the other points _in the database_, or _of the 10 selected points_?

Comment: @bcdan,.. sorry for the delay... it's 10 selected points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are needing to find points from your database that are at least 100 meters away from all the other points in the database:

This is a fairly simple problem. It can be visualized as an nxn matrix, with the point set as the rows and columns. In Python, comparing all the distances would look like:

```
selected = []
for pt1 in pts:
  inRange = True
  for pt2 in pts:
    if pt1.distanceTo(pt2) < 100:
      inRange = False
      break
  if inRange:
    selected.append(pt1)
```

This function iterates through the whole list of points. For each point, it checks the distance from the current point to all the other points. If all the other points are outside 100 meters, it adds the point to an array.

For the distance formula, please see the **haversine formula** [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) in code form.

Since you did not specify a language in your question, I will let you translate this into whatever language you need. This is just pseudocode, since not enough details were provided to answer your question with actual code.

Also, if I misunderstood your question, you can adapt this algorithm in some way. It is just to provide some ideas.